# Google Maps JavaScript API hyperlink obscuring

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on embedding a Google traffic map into an HTML window for a digital signage application (primarily for the purpose of digitizing event flyers and building directories) to be used at government facilities. The problem lies in the fact that the digital signage kiosk will be largely unattended, so that if a user were to click on the Google logo, the terms of service, etc., it would launch a new Chrome window over top of the application and the user (perhaps a malefactor) would be able to very quickly access sites far from the intended purpose of this application.

Is it unlawful to place transparent DIVs over top of the links, so this would not happen? If so, how can I stay within the terms of service, but also make sure users are not able to compromise the application or system, even?

Comment: what kind of browser are you going to use in your kiosk?

Comment: The application is running Chrome version 26.

Comment: have you considered going with this option https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/1375678#kiosk ?

Comment: I hadn't, thanks for the suggestion. I would love to do that, but it doesn't seem like that will solve the problem. I'm rendering my map essentially in an iFrame within the digital signage application. The problem is that when someone clicks the Google icon or the terms of services, that opens a full Chrome browser at that point and the browser renders on top of the signage application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I did for this:
https://youtu.be/7ZBBDFprYBg

It basically replaces the attributes for that `<a>` tag.

```
document.querySelector(".gmnoprint.gm-style-cc").querySelector('a').href = '#';
document.querySelector(".gmnoprint.gm-style-cc").querySelector('a').target = '';
```

Best Regards,
Eugene

Comment: So, this should work, right?

function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 38.8997685, lng: -77.0400586}
    
  });
  
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);

document.querySelector(".gmnoprint.gm-style-cc").querySelector('a').href = '#';
document.querySelector(".gmnoprint.gm-style-cc").querySelector('a').target = '';
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap&signed_in=false" async defer>
</script>